# Mongo DB and hashed password. Using the same database on another node application

Tags: mongodb, express, hash, passwords, passport.js

I have a web application currently running with a database. The database stores the password as hashed(salt and hash). How do i use the same database on another application? Will the existing users on the other application able to login to new application?

Comment: Provided you use the same algo for your password hashing, then there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one can use same database provided the schema requirements are same. Also on updating user profile , the changes will reflect on both application using it .